# Kivy image button stretching

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make a button with an image. However the image is stretched out. Is there a way I can make it a "fixed position", so whenever the Resolution changes, it won't get stretched out (using python)?

```
self.add_widget(Button(background_normal=('Image.png'),size_hint_x=(0.5),size_hint_y=(0.3),pos_hint={"x":0.3, "top":0.7}))
```

Comment: Can't you give it button dimensions directly? Not using `size_hint`?

Comment: I dont think so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is another thing you can do here by using the Kivy Behaviors module.

In your python file:

```
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass

self.add_widget(ImageButton(source=('Image.png'),size=(200,200), size_hint=(None,None),pos_hint={"x":0.3, "top":0.7}))
```

The ImageButton can now access both Button properties (like the 'on_press' method) as well as Image properties (including 'keep_ratio' and allow_stretch) which default to True and False, which is what you want in this example.

Comment: I tried it and it works except that when I click it nothing happens. Its like its just an image.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't flash like a button? You have to go back and set an image for each state (background_normal, background_down, background_normal_disabled, background_down_disabled). 

Similar to my previous answer, however now the image should keep its ratio regardless of state.

Comment: Would I add `on_press=("Screen")` so when you click it its going go to that screen?

Comment: Screens require a screen manager object to change the screen. [See Kivy ScreenManager documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html)

Comment: I have that in a kv file and everything. But I keep getting this error. -

TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
-
`self.add_widget(ImageButton(source=('Image.png'),size=(200,200), size_hint=(0.2, 0.2),on_press=(Screen),pos_hint={"x":0.3, "top":0.7}))`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
self.add_widget(Button(background_normal=('Image.png'),size=(200,200), size_hint=(None,None),pos_hint={"x":0.3, "top":0.7}))
```

You can of course change `(200, 200)` to whatever dimensions you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just to flesh out the answer slightly, I ended up with this:

```
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self,background_normal=None,background_down=None,**kwargs):
        super(ImageButton,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.border = (0,0,0,0)
        if background_normal is None:
            self.background_normal = self.source
        else:
            self.background_normal = background_normal
        self.background_down=background_down

self.add_widget(ImageButton(source=('Image.png'), size_hint=(0.1,0.1),pos_hint={"x":0.3, "top":0.7}))
```

which accomplishes a few things. Since it's a scaling performance that is desired to go with variable resolution, the button size should probably be a size_hint and not an absolute size. Otherwise, a hard-coded absolute size would end up being too big or too small for certain resolutions. Secondly, zeroing the `border` attribute is often a better default to avoid distorting the button images. Finally, adding `background_normal/down` to the constructor tidies up the code a bit since they aren't available in the ButtonBehavior constructor.

However, note that with this arrangement, the final layout size of the button has two possible outcomes, depending on which dimension of the parent layout is the limiting size. If that isn't acceptable, but the size_hint approach is still desired, then it would be necessary to assign one governing dimension for the button (either x or y), and use a callback to copy the size from the governing dimension to the dependent dimension at the time of do_layout().